# Turbo Capture Mode - Not recognising a click into another field

Tags: eggplant

I am new to Eggplant and I'm trying a login script using turbo capture mode on an application called Teamcenter PLM.

I have created the script however it won't recognise the click into the password field.

It is generating an error'FAILURE Screen_Error.png File not found click Error - Could not open image'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Adding more details will help you get answers to your question. For example, could you add the script code itself?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is you are referencing a captured image file by name that doesn't exist in the images directory. Eggplant will crash if it is asked to use an image file which doesn't exist.

One way or another you will need to make sure eggplant is aware of every image you want to work with.

- You may have mistyped the name of the image. In which case you will need to reference the correct image name.
- You could also capture a new image that is named correctly.

In general step debugging through test cases and identifying when the expected actions begin to differ from the actual actions is the best way to figure out what is wrong with a test script, once you've fixed obvious issues like imagefilenotfound errors.